# Is it possible to custom dialog theme in Android API 8

Tags: android, dialog, android-theme

I've spent all day trying to find this to no avail! I want a summary for my users after using my app, and a simple dialog is the obvious solution. However, I am unable to customise the theme to change the background and buttons. Every tutorial and explanation I've found on this matter is using API 11 techniques and I'm targeting API 8.

Is there a way to set the dialog theme for API 8 so I can change the background drawable, font, icons, etc? I've found various techniques for changing font, icon, adding a drawable, etc. (eg. http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application), but nothing that changes the background graphic or colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//set up dialog
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
```

Just specify a custom layout file for you dialog and specify there all the attributes you need including background drawable etc.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that and it seems to work, although I've found the ViewFlipper between asking the question and your answer, and that's a lot more straightforward and flexible for me to get my head around. ;)